# Handling uniqueness concurrently in event-based systems

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, mutual-exclusion

In the project I am working on right now, we have what we call challenges. Challenges have *members* and *participants*. Members are everyone who has access to the challenge (which can be both single users or groups of users), and participants track statistics about participation on a per user basis.

Challenge participants are recalculated each time a new challenge member is added. This happens event-based, so that challenge member triggers a `created` event, which challenge participant listens for.

The problem arises when two challenge members are created at the same time, meaning the event is also triggered twice, and two executions of the code runs concurrently. To illustrate:

```
challenge.getMembers();
challenge.getParticipants();

// calculations

foreach member not in participants, create participant
```

As said, the problem arises when the above code is running concurrently, more specifically when the second executions reaches `getParticipants` before the first has created the participant entries there were missing. Both executions see that some participants are missing, and creates them. This means that we now have duplicate entries of challenge participant for some users.

Right now our solution to this problem is to have a unique index on `challenge_id, user_id` in challenge participant. It does feel a bit dirty however to just ignore the error when violating the constraint. It also makes it harder to check for other SQL errors, since all errors are just passed to the callback, and we would then have to check the content of the error string to see whether it was an error we like (uniqueness violation), or an error we don't like (such as bad syntax), that should be handled.

This code will run on several servers, so even with mutices we are not guaranteed that the code will not run concurrently. We also don't mind it running concurrently for *different* challenges, as long as it does not run concurrently for the same challenge. Does anyone have suggestions for handling concurrent merges of this type?

Comment: The simply solution (however probably not too efficient) would be to maintain a lock per challenge in your database, or some sort of cache/shared-memory-layer accessible to all your servers. However the bigger problem is in your design; why are you creating all participants when a new member is added? Why do you not just create each member as a participant when that member is added? Also, you should have that unique constraint on your db just incase, even if you feel that the case shouldn't happen. It's a good fallback incase your code is not as good as you think it is.

Comment: What does your schema look like for the challenges, participants and members look like?

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you don't mind running the code concurrently for different challenges, you could have a column with state in challenges table. Then you would issue an `UPDATE challenges SET state = {locked} WHERE id = {id} AND state = {unlocked}`. If this query succeeds and affected rows equals 1, then you may proceed updating the participants and unlocking the challenge afterwards. If the query does not affect any rows then the challenge is probably being updated by some other thread of execution so you might want to either just skip this step or schedule it to be re-run later.

If you go this route then you'll need to be careful to unlock your challenges and do something that prevents them from being stuck if one of threads crashes in the middle of update and does not unlock it's challenge. You could for example have `state = {thread id}` and then you could detect which threads are dead and unlock their challenges.